# Contents on azure media service are streamed at very slow speed

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am having a content on azure media service which is played via azure media player.
Now the problem is all of the videos have started buffering a lot and it takes lot of time to start one video sometimes it just quits.
As far as traffic is concerned I am the only person who is using the media service right now.
Is this related to steaming units ?
Can anyone point me to correct path to diagnose the problem ?

Comment: How are you testing?  What's the bandwidth available, and at what device is this being tested ?

Comment: I have around 20-30 mbps line available.
I am testing that from my website.
I am using chrome on windows pc.

Comment: @SaurabhRajguru what is the website you are using to test, where is your location and where is the data center that your content is being streamed from? Are you using a CDN or using directly from the origin?  Lastly, when a timeout occurs there is an error code that is given. Can you please provide that, along with the manifest URL.  You might also want to run a fiddler network trace to see how long the segments are taking to download.

Can you please check this site: http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer to see if you are also seeing an issue with our samples.

Comment: Also, could you please provide a screenshot of the network request panel from Chrome? This can help us have a better understanding of the issue, too.